# Making the php code execute in browser using PHPstorm

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

So PHPstorm is running the php code fine in its console when I click run, that's great but I want to see it in the browser.

So I created a new PHP web application inside PHPstorm, set up the server to "localhost:8000".

[image: PHPstorm screenie]

Now when I click RUN it opens the browser but I get an error message: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8000"

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a web server running listening to that port?

Comment: If you using PHP **5.4**, it has built-in web server .. and PhpStorm supports it as well (use `PHP Built-in Web Server` type of configuration). More details on built-in server functionality: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Small blog post about built-in 5.4 web server support in PhpStorm: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-support-of-php-5-4-built-in-web-server/

Comment: @LazyOne maybe you should write up those comments as an answer so that this question can be marked 'answered'

Comment: Guys so I tried using PHP's built in server thingy, I also tried to initialize the PHP server through the terminal, it says that the server is initialized and listening to the localhost:8000... But still no success, chrome is still telling me there's nothing there, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure a run configuration for your project first.

Go to `Run -> Edit Configurations`, click on "PHP Built-in Web Server" and then press "+". You should see something like this:

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

After saving the settings you can run the web server via `Run -> Run '<project-name>'`. It should now serve up the pages to your browser.