# PhpStorm code preview

Tags: phpstorm

In **PhpStorm**, is there any way to add a panel to show a **html/php code preview** (like in RapidPhp) ?

[image]

Comment: Nope. You may try Live Edit plugin (works with Chrome) or some general 3rd party solutions (like Live Reload) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could run you pages in the browser if you enable the `PHP Built-in Web Server`

*Referenceing:*
*[Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15667500/4649882)*

> You have to configure a run configuration for your project first.
>
> Go to Run -> Edit Configurations, click on "PHP Built-in Web Server"
> and then press "+". You should see something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Run/Debug Configurations
>
> After saving the settings you can run the web server via Run -> Run
> ''. It should now serve up the pages to your browser.